# State selector for a custom button layout (i.e. LinearLayout)

Tags: android, layout

I'm wondering if it's possible to build a custom button layout with different appearance depending on state so it acts like a button. For example, a LinearLayout with an ImageView and TextView, with these states.

- When the button is in *normal state*, display `image_normal.png` and text in red.
- When the button is **pressed**, display `image_pressed.png`, background red and text in white.
- When the button is **disabled**, display `image_disabled.png` and text in grey.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Any view can have any background and any view can be made clickable, so there is nothing preventing you from having a `LinearLayout` with the background you described. It's worth noting that you don't need a `LinearLayout` to have an image next to text, you can use the fact that `TextView` supports drawables on any side of the text using the `drawable[Left|Top|Right|Bottom]` attributes.

If your question is about the syntax of a `selector` drawable, I would refer you to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#selector-element). Note that Android evaluates states top to bottom, so choose the order wisely. The last item should be the "default" state when none of the ones above apply. For the example you gave, you would probably have something like

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="..." />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="..." />
    <item android:drawable="..." /> <!-- disabled -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks Karakuri. I know how to create a selector for one view, but I don't know if it's possible to make different selectors for the different subviews, and how to "synchronize" all of them. (Also thanks for the suggestion about a TextView, in this case I think I can use that, although I'd like to know how to create any button layout).

Comment: @FerranMaylinch You can give the child views `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to make them have the same state as their parent view. In that case, if every child also has a state-list drawable, those will use the same state as the parent.